# Setting custom SVG icon for external GeoJSON point layer in Leaflet

Tags: leaflet, geojson, markers, svg

I am attempting to make a public transport map of Berlin within Leaflet.   I have exported layers from QGIS as GeoJSON and edited the file and added a var within a text editor.  I am having some trouble with my points layer, I would like customize the icon to be a SVG image of the U-bahn public transport system in Berlin.

I have attempted to do this by creating a variable:

```
var ubahn_icon = L.icon({
    iconUrl:'ubahn_.svg', 
    iconSize:[5,5],
    iconAnchor: [10, 10],
});
```

and then calling that variable within the Ubahn train stations point layer:

```
var  ubahnstations = L.geoJSON(ubahnstations,  {style: function(feature) {
    return {
        icon: ubahn_icon
    };
}


}
).addTo(map);
```

However I just get the default icon.

My code in it's entirety :

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.9.4/dist/leaflet.css"
        integrity="sha256-p4NxAoJBhIIN+hmNHrzRCf9tD/miZyoHS5obTRR9BMY="
        crossorigin=""/>
        

        <script src="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.9.3/dist/leaflet.js" integrity="sha256-WBkoXOwTeyKclOHuWtc+i2uENFpDZ9YPdf5Hf+D7ewM=" crossorigin=""></script>
        <script src="zones6.js"></script>
        <script src="ubahnlinien.js"></script>
        <script src="ubahnstations.js"></script>
<style>
    #map { height: 400px; }
</style>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<title>Berlin Netzplan</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        
        <div id="map"></div>

<script> var map = L.map('map').setView([52.5200, 13.4050], 10);

L.tileLayer('https://tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {
    maxZoom: 19,
    attribution: '&copy; <a href="http://www.openstreetmap.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a>'
}).addTo(map);



var ubahn_icon = L.icon({
    iconUrl:'ubahn_.svg', 
    iconSize:[5,5],
    iconAnchor: [10, 10],
});
   




var zones6 = L.geoJSON(zones6, {style: function (feature) {
    return {
      color: feature.properties.color
    };
  }
}).addTo(map)


var ubahnlinien = L.geoJSON(ubahnlinien, {style: function (feature) {
    return {
      color: feature.properties.Color
    };
  }
}).addTo(map)

var  ubahnstations = L.geoJSON(ubahnstations,  {style: function(feature) {
    return {
        icon: ubahn_icon

    };
}


}
).addTo(map);

</script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Editied.  I appeciate your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use `pointToLayer` GeoJSON layer option to assign nonstandard icons to GeoJSON layer points (see https://leafletjs.com/reference.html#geojson).

In your case relevant part of the code should then look like this:

```
var ubahnstations = L.geoJSON(ubahnstations, {
  pointToLayer: function (feature, latlng) {
    var myMarker =  L.marker(latlng, {
      icon: ubahn_icon
    });
    return myMarker;
  }
}).addTo(map);
```

Comment: Thank you for your response.  I copied it into my code however my editor showed an error. I think there is missing a closed )?  Also where does the addTO(map) go? I guess at the end?

Comment: Yes, see corrected answer.

Comment: Thank you!______

Comment: I was still celebrating!  I've marked it as solved. Thanks again